# Speech to Text works fine on emulator but I get an error on phone

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to run the code below which runs fine on the emulator but then I get a `Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.` [exception](/questions/tagged/exception) at `RecognizeWithUIAsync()` if I run it on the device.

```
// Compile the dictation grammar    
await speechRecog.CompileConstraintsAsync();

// Start Recognition    
SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await this.speechRecog.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

// Show Output    
var sttDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(speechRecognitionResult.Text, "Heard You said...");

await sttDialog.ShowAsync();
```

Some additional info: 
My method is [async](/questions/tagged/async); I checked microphone permissions at the manifest file and I have four voices installed on my device.